# Как вставить переменную JavaScript в html код

Tags: javascript, html

```
Переменная = "http://adressaita/papka/"
<img src="**Переменная**File.jpg">
```

Как сделать чтобы эта переменная вставилась в код, а файл .js хранился на удалённом сервере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Страница HTML на одном домене

```
<html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.myVar = "http://adressaita/papka/";
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gde-to-tam/script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

Файл http://gde-to-tam/script.js на другом домене

```
document.write('<img src="' + window.myVar + 'File.jpg">');
```

---

Таким способом часто подключают счётчики и баннеры. На странице HTML определяют в javascript переменные с настройками (домен, цвета, размеры), а в подключаемом скрипте эти переменные используются.

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = "http://adressaita/papka/",
link = document.getElementById('myLink');
link.setAttribute('href', href);
```

Comment: Так, как в php, не получится. Есть свойство innerHTML, но оно не всегда подходит.